# How to write click event in inside of cellrenderer angular ag grid

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

`enter code here`I am trying to create edit and delete buttons in same column for every row using angular ag grid. To display the edit and delete buttons, I am using icons. I am able to display the remove and edit icons for every row in ag grid, but i am failing to click those icons.
Below are the respective images of that. I tried to click event inside of button but it was not worked, I tried to write click event in icon tag also but it is also not worked.
Below is my code which i am using

Comment: Please don't share illegible photos of your screen. It's better to share code excerpts as it makes our lives much easier.

Comment: @WillAlexander I updated my code, Can you look on to it

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this approach to create a click event in cell renderer.

**First : Create Button Cell**

create button cell renderer as an Angular component that implements the `ICellRendererAngularComp` interface as follows :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'btn-cell-renderer',
  template: `
    <button (click)="handleClickEvent($event)">Click me</button>
  `,
})
export class BtnCellRenderer implements ICellRendererAngularComp
{
  private params: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  handleClickEvent() {
    this.params.clicked(this.params.value);
  } 
 
}
```

The params object is accessed through the agInit hook.

**Second:  Register the `BtnRenderer` in the app module**

// app/app.modules.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([BtnCellRenderer]),
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, BtnCellRenderer],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

**Third:  Use the renderer**
Use the renderer in your component as follows

```
// app/app.component.ts

this.columnDefs = [
      {
        field: 'action',
        cellRenderer: 'btnCellRenderer',
        cellRendererParams: {
          clicked: function(field: any) {
            alert(`${field} was clicked`);
          }
        },
        minWidth: 100,
      }
     
      ];
      
      this.frameworkComponents = {
      btnCellRenderer: BtnCellRenderer
    };
```

Comment: I need to display both edit and delete buttons and there respective functionality in one column(action). I am struggling there. If i follow your way i am able to display only one button in one column

Answer (score 1):

You can follow kplus answer and in order to display two buttons create two renderer and bind them separately with edit and delete button in your columnDefs.

```js
  columnDefs = [
  {
      field: 'edit', cellRenderer: 'editRenderer',
      headerClass: 'my-header-class',
      cellRendererParams: {
        onClick: this.onClickEdit.bind(this)
      }
    },
    {
      field: 'Delete',cellRenderer: 'deleteRenderer',
      headerClass: 'my-header-class',
      cellRendererParams: {
        onClick: this.onClickDelete.bind(this)
      }
    }];
    
     onClickEdit(params) {
     //code
     }
     
     onClickDelete(params) {
     //code
     }
     
     
     
    constructor() {
    this.frameworkComponents = {
      editRenderer: EditComponent,
      deleteRenderer: DeleteCompoenent
    }
```